# wpf - Dynamically Moving TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a TextBlock that I create during run-time:

```
TextBlock firstBlock = new TextBlock();
firstBlock.Text = "Mary Joe";
firstBlock.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, -1500, 0);
firstBlock.FontSize = 72;
firstBlock.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
firstBlock.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
myGrid.Children.Add(firstBlock);
```

I want to be able to move the TextBlock down the Y-axis smoothly. I've thought to use DoubleAnimation, but I couldn't find a property to alter in order to move it. I would also like to make the text smaller as it goes downwards (kind of like a reverse Stars Wars Credits, but no 3D). I know this stuff is pretty simple to make in xaml, but I want to be able to call the animation at certain times and add new text each time in the blocks. I've searched around a lot to no avail. I figured I would post here to see if smart people could help me :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a TranslateTransform on the TextBlock to move it. Use a double animation on the Y property.

For the FontSize use another double animation to shrink the value. Put them both in a Storyboard and you can run them at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your response! By letting me know of TranslateTransform, I was able to find another question that showed me what the code looks like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841124/wpf-animating-translatetransform-from-code).

Comment: I do not recommend using an animation on FontSize. Use ScaleTransform instead.